# There is no counter in inline python?

Tags: python, loops, inline

When I'm trying to put counter in inline loop of Python, it tells me the syntax error. Apparently here it expects me to assign a value to `i` not `k`.

Could anyone help with rewriting the inline loop?

```
aa = [2, 2, 1]
k = 0

b = [k += 1 if i != 2  for i in aa ] 

print(b)
```

Comment: That is not an "inline loop". List comprehensions are not a nifty way to write arbitrary `for` loops; they are for *building lists*.

Comment: `count = sum([i != 2  for i in aa ] )`

Comment: What were you even expecting `b` to be after that?

Comment: Hi @user2357112, ideally I'm expecting to get [2,1]. To count how many times "2" shows up in the list and keep the rest of the list as it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what you're doing. This:

```
[x for y in z]
```

is not an "inline for loop". A `for` loop can do *anything*, iterating on any iterable object. One of the things a `for` loop can do is create a list of items:

```
my_list = []
for i in other_list:
    if condition_is_met:
        my_list.append(i)
```

A list comprehension covers *only this use case* of a `for` loop:

```
my_list = [i for i in other_list if condition_is_met]
```

That's why it's called a "list comprehension" and not an "inline for loop" - because it *only creates lists*. The other things you might use a `for` loop for, like iterating a number, you can't directly use a list comprehension to do.

For your particular problem, you're trying to use `k += 1` in a list comprehension. This operation doesn't return anything - it just modifies the variable `k` - so when python tries to assign that to a list item, the operation fails. If you want to count up with `k`, you should either just use a regular `for` loop:

```
for i in aa:
    if i != 2:
        k += 1
```

or use the list comprehension to *indirectly* measure what you want:

```
k += len([i for i in aa if i != 2])
```

Here, we use a list comprehension to construct a list of every element `i` in `aa` such that `i != 2`, then we take the number of elements in that list and add it to `k`. Since this operation actually produces a list of its own, the code will not crash, and it will have the same overall effect. This solution isn't always doable if you have more complicated things you'd like to do in a `for` loop - and it's slightly less efficient as well, because this solution requires actually creating the new list which isn't necessary for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer! Much appreciated. May I ask a further question? Is it possible to realize "list comprehension" and iteration at the same time? E.g. To convert [True, False, False, False, True] to [0,3,4]. "0", and "4" represent the position, while "3" is the count of "False"

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to do that with a list comprehension. They're a useful tool, but it's not like `for` loops are to be avoided or anything, and for a task like that I would just use a `for` loop (basically do a finite-state-machine thing or something)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `len()` like so

```
print(len([i for i in a if i != 2]))
```